# Why android studio always crashed? (Intent)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

Do you have any idea why using intent always crash in Android Studio?

```
public void signin(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Sign_In.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

That's my simple code and it wouldn't work! I mean it crashed. I used same codes before and it works. What do you think the reason why I couldn't Intent a layout or other activity? I'd clean and rebuild the project..

Comment: show some error log in logcat.

Comment: Excuse me sir! How can I paste log cat? Too many info. Sorry beginner

Comment: first checkout how to see logcat in android studio then find it and then paste your error here

Comment: I know sir how to see the logcat. The problem sir is I didnt know what information could I paste here. :( Sorry sir beginner

Comment: try searching for 'signin' in logcat and see if some error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your Sign_In class is throwing exception in oncreate method check it by removing all code of oncreate method hope it help you

Comment: Thank you sir it works! But.... I have follow up question. What if I use oncreate method in Sign_In class? How can I retrieved that? Sorry for grammar sir

Comment: check your on create method their is any variable that is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. Let's assume the Activity you made the Intent with is called MainActivity:

```
public void signin(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sign_In.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And if it still doesn't work, leave a comment here.

Comment: @Lawrence  What's the name of the Activity you want to start the Sign_In.class from?

Comment: Mobile_Grocery_App sir!

Comment: public void signin(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Mobile_Grocery_App.this, Sign_In.class);
    startActivity(i);
}